# Errors which I face in a React.js project

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on integrating maps in my react project. I am getting some errors. I used typescript in my project. Below script I used in my typescript React.js file.

Below is a code which shows error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        (function() {
            var placesAutocomplete = places({
            appId: 'pl8OXN3L',
            apiKey: 'a6eb12dbd7cf7b2fd',
            container: document.querySelector('#address')
            });

            var $address = document.querySelector('#address-value')
            placesAutocomplete.on('change', function(e:any) {
            $address.textContent = e.suggestion.value  -------------// #1
            });

            placesAutocomplete.on('clear', function() {
            $address.textContent = 'none';   -----------------------// #2
            });

            })();
```

This are errors which I am facing:

#1 and #2 which will show error at $address.

It is indicate that Object is possibly 'null'. ts(2531)

Kindly give me solutions to overcome to this error.

Comment: Are these errors, or warnings? Either way it is implying that `$address` is possibly null/undefined, in other words, the `document.querySelector('#address-value')` might not find a match. You later access a `textContent` property, which will throw an error if `$address` is null/undefined. You should do a null/undefined check prior to accessing nested properties. If this is a React project why are you mixing jQuery in? React and jQuery have rather orthogonal approaches to front end UI.

Comment: This are errors not a warnings. I used jQuery in react because of through React  i can't able to integrate map location in my project so that i used jQuery.

Now what to do in a code to solve this ??